# MVC Web API custom basic authentication

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a database with users, the users can have different roles.

I want to implement basic authentication for my MVC Web API and I want to be able to tag methods with an `Authorize` tag and also pass `userType` as a parameter.

```
[Authorize(admin)]
public bool Test()
{
}

[Authorize(user)]
public bool Test1()
{
}
```

I can't figure out how to make this attribute, for example how do I make an attribute that simply makes a method always return `false`?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class TestAttribute: System.Attribute 
{
  //Return false?
}
```

I'm looking for some advice.

EDIT:

I made the following class:

```
 ilterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
                }
            }
        }

        private void CacheValidateHandler(HttpContext context, object data, ref HttpValidationStatus validationStatus)
        {
```

then i add [BasicAuthorize] to a method, but it still let me access it without basic autentication.

any idea?

Comment: You want to check roles, but your code checks user name and password against a data layer. Where is your role check?

Comment: I was just trying to get the basic auth to work, but i can't get any code to run it BasicAuthorizeAttribute at all right now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read some basics about authorization and authentication and how the [Authorize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute can be applied.

Roles are out of the box. Just use the built-in capabilities of the `Authorize` attribute: Example:

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
public bool Test()
{
}
```

If you need a custom implementation you need to inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` instead of from `System.Attribute`. Everything else is pretty straight forward from here. Basic example explained here: [Basic Authorization Attribute in ASP.NET MVC](https://chodounsky.net/2012/05/02/basic-authorization-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: I tried the code in your link, but still does not work, updated my question, please see.

Comment: It looks like you just copy and paste code without understanding the principles behind. Do you have a role "admin" If not, that might be the reason why my mentioned dummy sample doesn't work. Also, use the `Roles` property as per its intended use.